# Is it possible to launch the iPhone simulators contacts from another app

Tags: ios4

I am trying to use the contacts from iPhone simulator's or iPhone contacts in my native app.

For this I searched a lot and found that `application:openUrl` method can be used but this method is invoked in `applicationdidFinishedLaunching` method.
And I want it to launch the already exist contacts app in my native app.

Answer (score 0):

What are you wanting the user to do with the Contacts?

The API sample for doing anything with the address book is listed under QuickContacts.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html

From the README:

> This sample also shows how to:
>
> - Browse a list of Address Book contacts and allow users to choose a contact from that list.
>
>   - Display and edit information associated with a selected contact.
>   - Prevent users from performing default actions such as dialing a phone number associated with a selected information.
>   - Create a new contact record.
>   - Update a partial contact record.
>   - Present and dismiss the people picker, person view controller, new-person view controller, and unknown-person view controller.

Comment: i want the user can select the number from list

Comment: What do you specifically want shown for the list of contacts, the name, and when you select it it what do you want done with the number? If you look in the sample I gave you, it shows a method called (void)showPeoplePickerController which will display a modal view containing the Contacts list for them to pick from. You need to ensure your current controller is a delegate of ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate as well.

Comment: i just wanna display the number on the uilabel .

Comment: i am also using navigation controller in that i am pushing uiviewcontroller.

Comment: Your UIViewController needs to be a delegate of ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate; something along the lines of @interface MyContoller : UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> and then implement the function showPeoplePickerController like they do in the link I posted.